# Does all new apps have also to work on iPad to pass the appstore approval process?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

A friend of mine told me that there is a new rule to pass the appstore approval process. The app also have to work on iPad otherwise it would get rejected. I didn't find something which supports his statement. Does somebody know what is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is part of the new App Store guidelines posted by Apple.

Section 2.10 says: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution.

You normally need a dev account to read these guidelines, but in the meantime they have been mirrored by other people. Google for "app store guidelines" and you'll find the document.

Comment: How can I do that without owning an iPad? Does it somehow work within the simulator?

Comment: Yes, it will work in the simulator, though it's always better to try it on a device before releasing (good excuse to buy an iPad too).

Comment: So I only would have to choose iPad in the iPhone Simulator? Yeah, good excuse.

Comment: Or you can ask somebody who has an iPad to test your app for you.

Comment: This not entirely true. As an example, if an iPhone app requires iOS 4 to run, then it is fairly obvious that, at least until iOS 4.2 is out, the app can not run on the iPad which is still tied to iOS 3.2.

Comment: The single biggest thing you can do to make sure your application works as a basic iPhone application on the iPad is not do any device-specific checks.  Apple singled this out as the biggest reason why some iPhone applications crashed on startup on an iPad when it first came out.  Instead, check for the presence of features or API that you need.