# Is developing an ipad app mandatory?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I was reading appstore review guideline and I am little confused on this lines:

```
iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
```

What does that mean? I have to develop for both iphone and ipad? I want to develop apps just for iphone for now...

Comment: This probably would be a better fit on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: just make sure you app don't crash on ipad is enough

Comment: @CoffeeRain I didn't know apple.stackexchange.com thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key phrase is "at iPhone resolution". In other words, the iPhone app must run successfully in *iPhone emulation mode* on the iPad. Just about every iPhone app will do that automatically, but they are just making sure that you've made sure.

Answer (score 4):

It means that your apps should also run on iPad, but you don't have to develop iPad apps.

Just test it on iPad simulator, if it works it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like new iOS apps might need to run on both.

Although just being able run instead of optimized for iPad is probably good enough.

Duplicate of:
[Does all new apps have also to work on iPad to pass the appstore approval process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901731/does-all-new-apps-have-also-to-work-on-ipad-to-pass-the-appstore-approval-proces)